# ASP.net Uploadify Querystring textbox value

Tags: asp.net, uploadify, multifile-uploader

On referring to this post [ASP.net Uploadify Querystring checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354598/asp-net-uploadify-querystring-checkbox-value), I simply tried to pass the value of a textbox control to FileUploads.aspx.cs but I am unable to get the value, neither using with POST method nor with GET.

```
<p>
  <asp:TextBox ID="tbTrainingName" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<div id="fuFiles"></div>  

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#fuFiles').uploadify({
   // Some options
  'method'   : 'GET',
  'uploader': '_scripts/uploadify.swf',
  'script': 'FileUploads.aspx?trainingName=' + ('[id$=tbTrainingName]').val()  '',
  'cancelImg': '_scripts/cancel.png',
  'auto': 'true',
  'multi': 'true',
  'buttonText': 'Upload Files...',
  'queueSizeLimit': 3,
  'simUploadLimit': 2
  });
  });

   In FileUploads.aspx.cs

   HttpPostedFile uploads = Request.Files["FileData"];
   string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads.FileName);
```

I am unable to see any thing in Request.QueryString. Could you help me where I am wrong!! Also if you have any good suggession other than uploadify, please suggest, I am using asp.net 4.0.

Comment: where is `FileData` coming from? Shouldn't you just be using `tbTrainingName.Text` ?

Comment: yes but FileUploads.aspx.cs is another file and tbTrainingName is another file.

Comment: then why did you post that in your question? Where is FileData coming from exactly then?

Comment: yes but FileUploads.aspx.cs is a separate file and i am using the uploadify in Trainings.aspx. I think it would be better if I use the same file and extract the value of textbox just by tbTrainingName.Text. It would be ok then. Thanks

Comment: Let me check if I could achieve this in this way!!

Comment: Ultimately i had to use session variable because page is posting back!!

Answer (score 1):

It's all in your timing...

In your example code you are setting the `script` property from the dropdown value (e.g. using `('[id$=tbTrainingName]').val()`) **at the time the uploadify is created** (i.e. at page load).

You need to set the value *after* the file is selected, but *before* the file begins to upload.

We wound up turning off the `auto` property and using a separate upload button to trigger the upload. We change the form data when that upload button was clicked, but before we tell uploadify to begin. On the server we extracted the user selections from the form data.

**Note: We are using the latest uploadify*